# Im trying to subtract the stock number (quantity) and the purchase of customer (quantity2)

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, e-commerce

Im trying to subtract the stock number (quantity) and the purchase of customer (quantity2) from 2 different tables and I want the result go to the (resultNew) thank you in advance.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cart");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"insert into transaction 
                              values ('','$account','$namee','$datee','$quants','0')");
$sql .= mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE transaction 
                               INNER JOIN products 
                                   ON transaction.quantity2 = products.quantity
                               SET transaction.resultNew = quantity2-quantity 
                               WHERE productOrder = $namee ");
// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql))
{
    do
    {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con))
        {
            // Fetch one and one row
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                printf("%s\n",$row[0]);
            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Update your question with the code instead of a screenshot

Comment: I already edited sir thank you. I am new here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please improve your question, add details, errors, and a well formatted code.

Comment: The first concern is you cannot concat your two $sql queries like that. You need to execute each one by themselves... then check results of each.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I tried to update the second $sql in different query but its working sir. When I subtract the two fields its starting to not work because they are on different table

Comment: @IncredibleHat I tried this query and its working on my third field (resultNew)

$sql = mysqli_query($connect,"insert into transaction values ('','$account','$namee','$datee','$quants','0')");
                                     $sql .= mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE transaction SET resultNew = quantity2-1 ");

Comment: See what you are doing wrong there: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php